# Divide two quaternions evenly by a scalar to get a smooth rotation in-between

Tags: unity, quaternion

How do you divide two quaternions - say `A` and `B` - evenly by a scalar, to calculate the rotations between them to render a smoother rotation?

> Effectively, say you want to smooth the rotations between `A` and `B`
> evenly by `n`. How do you calculate each quaternion value between A and B?

I have found that resorting to `.eulerAngles` leads to some wild gimbal locking, so I think the math needs to stay in quaternion space...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing `Quaternion.Slerp`. You can use this to generate quaternion at any particular fraction of the rotation between a start and an end quaternion:

```
IEnumerator<Quaternion> RotationSteps(Quaternion from, Quaternion to, int stepCount) {

    yield return from;

    for(int i = 1; i < stepCount; i++) {
        yield return Quaternion.Slerp(
                        from,
                        to,
                        i / (float)stepCount
                     );
    }

    yield return to;
}
```

Or you can compute the incremental rotation of a single step like so:

```
Quaternion travel = to * Quaternion.Inverse(from);

Quaternion step = Quaternion.Slerp(
                      Quaternion.identity,
                      travel,
                      1f / stepCount
                  );
```

Comment: There is also a SmoothDamp implementation for Quaternions here, which has served me well: https://gist.github.com/maxattack/4c7b4de00f5c1b95a33b